# A pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I'm working on a homework assignment for my *C++* class and have ran across a problem that I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Just to note,  the separation of the files is necessary and I realize this would be much easier if I just made a structure `AttackStyles` inside the `main` and forgo the additional class file altogether.

The base of my problem is that I cannot seem to be able to loop through an array of classes and pull out base data.  Here is the code:

```
// AttackStyles.h
#ifndef ATTACKSTYLES_H
#define ATTACKSTYLES_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class AttackStyles
{
private:
    int styleId;
    string styleName;

public:
    // Constructors
    AttackStyles();  // default
    AttackStyles(int, string);

    // Destructor
    ~AttackStyles();

    // Mutators
    void setStyleId(int);
    void setStyleName(string);  

    // Accessors
    int getStyleId();
    string getStyleName();  

    // Functions

};
#endif


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// AttackStyles.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "AttackStyles.h"
using namespace std;


// Default Constructor
AttackStyles::AttackStyles()    
{}

// Overloaded Constructor
AttackStyles::AttackStyles(int i, string n)
{
    setStyleId(i);
    setStyleName(n);
}

// Destructor
AttackStyles::~AttackStyles()    
{}

// Mutator
void AttackStyles::setStyleId(int i)
{
    styleId = i;
}

void AttackStyles::setStyleName(string n)
{
    styleName = n;
}

// Accessors
int AttackStyles::getStyleId()
{
    return styleId;
}

string AttackStyles::getStyleName()
{
    return styleName;
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "attackStyles.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int STYLE_COUNT = 3;
    AttackStyles asa[STYLE_COUNT] = {AttackStyles(1, "First"), 
                                     AttackStyles(2, "Second"), 
                                     AttackStyles(3, "Third")};

    // Pointer for the array
    AttackStyles *ptrAsa = asa;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Style Id:\t" << ptrAsa->getStyleId << endl;
        cout << "Style Name:\t" << ptrAsa->getStyleName << endl;
        ptrAsa++;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My question is why do I get the error:

```
  "a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function"
```

on both `ptrAsa->getStyleId` and `ptrAsa->getStyleName`?

I cannot figure out what is wrong with this!

Comment: This is old, but don't use "using namespace std;" in a header file.  It messes up the namespace for every header included after it and the including file.

Answer (score 44):

You are missing `()` around the function calls. It should be `ptrAsa->getStyleId()`.

Answer (score 15):

You are missing parenthesis on both calls, it should be

```
ptrAsa->getStyleId()
```

to call the function.

```
ptrAsa->getStyleId
```

is used to refer to a member value / attribute.

Comment: OMG!   I'm just gonna crawl back into my hole now.
Extremely sorry for the stupid question  lol.

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke the function, not merely reference it:

```
    std::cout << "Style Id:\t" << ptrAsa->getStyleId() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Style Name:\t" << ptrAsa->getStyleName() << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are Forgot to put () in last in Your Function(ptrAsa->getStyleId ) Calling with arrow operator.